# pyglet No standard config is available, when trying to run openai gym inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker, openai-gym

I was able to get GUI from withing a docker container by following the instructions as seen in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDg6TRwiPtg). (Tested by trying to start up firefox)

I have installed OpenAI gym.

On trying to run the sample code as seen [here](https://gym.openai.com/docs/#installation) I get the following error

`libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gym/core.py", line 153, in render
    return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gym/core.py", line 285, in _render
    return self.env.render(mode, close)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gym/core.py", line 153, in render
    return self._render(mode=mode, close=close)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py", line 114, in _render
    from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 239, in <module>
    import pyglet.window
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1896, in <module>
    gl._create_shadow_window()
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 208, in _create_shadow_window
    _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/reinforcement-learning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 517, in __init__
    raise NoSuchConfigException('No standard config is available.')
pyglet.window.NoSuchConfigException: No standard config is available.`

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't opt out the opengl lib (e.g. specifying the -no-opengl-files option for the `.run` file) when installing the NVIDIA GPU driver, it may be the problem. I've got a laptop without those lib installed and got the container from a image containing gym environment to work. But on my PC with those opengl lib installed in addition to nvidia driver, the very same image as mentioned above didn't work and `pyglet.window.NoSuchConfigException` was raised. 
PS: I've tested on my PC via python3 console and found that Window could be created manually with `pyglet` outside container.

Comment: Installation switch is `--no-opengl-libs`. It can also be controlled from the Options menu in the installer.